# Custom Field in Sitecore XP 8.0 Client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8

I have to add a custom field ie. Drop List of country and auto populate the Drop List of cities on selection of respective country in Sitecore Client.

If possible we have to take the list of Countries and Cities from the Content Item.

Comment: If Somebody have Sollution Please share

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like this out of the box in Sitecore. What you need to do is to implement custom Sitecore field.

Short tutorials how to build one can be found:

- https://sdn.sitecore.net/articles/api/creating%20a%20composite%20custom%20field/adding%20a%20custom%20field%20to%20sitecore%20client.aspx
- http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/best-practice-blogs/martin-knudsen/posts/2012/09/creating-a-custom-sitecore-field.aspx

And here you can find an answer **how to build a custom field which uses one dropdown depending on another**:  **[Sitecore grouped droplist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574165/sitecore-grouped-droplist)**